# Are these two binary operations commutative? $x*y = (x+y)/(xy)$ or $x\&y=(x+1)/(y+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Are these two binary operations commutative?$$x*y = \frac{x+y}{xy}\\x\&y=\frac{x+1}{y+1}$$

Can you help me to identify if both of these are communtative or not?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you think? Does it _look_ like $x*y$ and $y*x$ ought to be the same? What about $x\mathbin{\&}y$ and $y\mathbin{\&}x$?

Comment: First one is comm. and second one is not. See if interchanging x and y affects the answer or not.

Comment: Welcome to the website! Attaching pictures of questions is not advised -- use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math equations in future.

Answer (score 1):

First binary operation is commutative.

\begin{align}
x*y&=\dfrac{x+y}{xy}\\
&=\dfrac{y+x}{yx}\\
&= y*x
\end{align}

Second binary operation is not commutative.

\begin{align}
x\&y&=\dfrac{x+1}{y+1}\\
&\neq\dfrac{y+1}{x+1}\text{, except } (y+1)^2=(x+1)^2\\
&= y\&x.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept this answer if this best answer for you.